# How to run multiple instance of WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-task-scheduler

I have developed a WinForms application for two purposes

1) It has a form which will accept configuration from user and store it

2) Based on configuration values entered in step 1. a task scheduler will be created that will transfer files from local folder to FTP

Now, when task is running from scheduler and at the same time if i open a form it will give me error like

```
Process/exe is already in use. Cannot start new instance.
```

Is it possible to open form in different instance to that of scheduler task?

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{

if (args.Length > 0 && args[0] == "AutoRun")
{
Logger.Info("Auto run successfull.");
GetConfigValues getConfigValues = new GetConfigValues();
UploadToFTP uploadToFTP = new UploadToFTP();
string result = uploadToFTP.UploadFile(getConfigValues.LocalPath, getConfigValues.FTPServer, getConfigValues.FTPFolderPath, getConfigValues.FTPUsername, getConfigValues.FTPPassword);
}
else
{
Logger.Info("Manual run successfull.");
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new Login());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, share your code

Comment: I think the only way you can get this working with windows task scheduler is to have multiple exe's  of the same application i.e. program1.exe, program2.exe. It would be better to write your own

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski  - Added code above. If run through scheduler i have parameter "AutoRun" else open form if opened through desktop icon.

Comment: Does the error message come from your own application?

Comment: What gives that error? Is this the exact error message you're getting? You can normally run as many instances of an executable as you want, so where does the restriction come from? Task scheduler? Your application? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is related to Task Scheduler and not your application specifically:

You can configure the behaviour of the Task Scheduler task when the target process is already running. In the UI, this is on the `Settings` tab, "If the task is already running...". The default is "Do not start a new instance"; what you want is probably "Run a new instance in parallel", though a better option would probably be to have a different executable for handling the background tasks, and queuing the consecutive runs instead.

Comment: Yes i have do so now. But this is happening occasionally. I will update if this error happens again.